# Proof of the distributive law in implication?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am doing a practice exam and in it is the following question:

Show without truth tables that the following logical equivalence holds:

$$(p → q) ∧ (p → r) ≡ p → (q ∧ r)$$

I attempted to substitute the left side's $(p \rightarrow q)$ and then apply the distributive laws, but what I got as a result was terribly long and messy.

I found a sample proof [over here](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Self-Distributive_Law_for_Conditional/Reverse_Implication/Formulation_1). However that is a proof using the tableau method of natural deduction and we still haven't covered that in class.

Is there a simpler proof?

Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the equivalence $\quad a \rightarrow b \equiv \lnot a \lor b\tag{1}\;$

to transform the implications into disjunctions,

then use one of the distributive laws you know $(2)$:

$$\begin{align}(p → q) ∧ (p → r) &\equiv (\lnot p \lor q) \land (\lnot p \lor r)\tag{by (1)}\\ \\ & \equiv \lnot p \lor (q\land r)\tag{by (2)} \\ \\ & \equiv p \rightarrow (q \land r)\tag{by (1)}\end{align}$$

Comment: Awesome @amWhy, thanks a lot! It was so simple, gah! I'll try even harder before asking next time. Thanks again!

Comment: Your welcome! We've all encountered exercises that "look" more difficult than they really need to be. ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: Always! :-)

Comment: This works the same with tautological consequence (or implication) right?